Movie or TV series episode where a summoning of a greenish spirit is interrupted
This is a bit of a long shot since I don't remember anything from this live-action movie or TV series episode except for this one (hopefully memorable) scene. It's actually possible I didn't watch the whole thing, just this scene. I watched this as a kid on TV, late '80s to mid '90s. Probably in German, but since I don't remember any actual dialogue at all, it's also possible I watched this while on vacation, in France or Spain.

In the scene, there was a round table or wide pedestal with a hole in the middle. Swords were lying on the table, arranged in a star pattern, with their tips pointing toward the hole, pommels outward.
People were standing around the table, chanting something. It's possible these summoners were all female. I think it was some interior location, but not sure.
As the chanting grew more and more frantic, a greenish apparition started forming above the hole, becoming slowly more opaque. I think the apparition resembled a knight in armor, but I might misremember that.
The summoning was interrupted by one or more people arriving at the scene. One of them drew a sword or a saber, whereupon the apparition vanished with an inhuman wail.
Finally, the swords on the table were cast into the hole.

Does anyone recognize this?

Update: Qev's answer suggests the movie Red Sonja, but this is not what I watched. I remember:

darker lighting than in Red Sonja,
more rhythmic chanting, getting almost frenzied towards the end, with the summoning almost complete (whereas in Red Sonja, the ritual is interrupted pretty early on in its progress),
the swords were lying on the table (possibly in sword-shaped indentations, though I'm not sure), not being held,
the table/pedestal didn't split, there was a static hole in the middle, too small to throw a person in, but large enough for swords,
a green spirit with a humanoid form, not a talisman. The spirit didn't disappear soundlessly like the guy in Red Sonja, but vanished (evaporated?) with a wail when threatened with a sword/saber.
the swords being cast into the hole simultaneously (whereas in Red Sonja, the priestesses are cast into the hole one after another).

Nevertheless, the setup as such in Red Sonja is so eerily similar to what I remember that I'm now wondering whether I'm conflating multiple things in my memory, or (hopefully) someone took a page out of Red Sonja's screenplay for their own production.

I suspect this might be the following scene from the 1985 film Red Sonja.  A group of white-robed priestesses are gathering in a ritual to destroy the evil (green glowing) Talisman--complete with a circle of swords pointing toward it, suspended over a hole--but are interrupted and slaughtered by the Big Bad and her minions:



In the aftermath of the battle, the Big Bad orders one of her male minions to touch the Talisman.  The unfortunate fellow is then instantly disintegrated in a flare of green light.

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, that video is geoblocked for me. I don't remember a talisman, more like a humanoid-looking spirit, and it emitted a wail when threatened with a sword/saber. I'll try to scare up that Red Sonja scene from somewhere, though.

If you gain access to the full movie, the scene above begins at around the 6:00 mark.  There isn't a spirit that disappears at any point, however one of Gedren's (male) minions touches the Talisman and is instantly disintegrated in a flash of green light.

I was able to watch the scene now, but, unfortunately, it's not what I remember. See the update to my question. But thanks a lot for trying!
